# Why does pbs(dsh) schedule my task onto one node?

Tags: scripting, distributed-computing, pbs

I want to execute foo.sh on 2 different nodes. Therefore, I wrote the following script:

```
#!/home/farago/bin/dash    
qsub -N dist -o P -e P-err -V -v 
  "EXECSCRIPT=foo.sh" 
  -l walltime=12:00:00,nodes=2:ppn=1 Cluster_ExecExp_pbsdsh.sh
```

with Cluster_ExecExp_pbsdsh.sh:

```
#!/home/farago/bin/dash
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=1 
#PBS -l walltime=12:00:00          
/usr/bin/pbsdsh -v dash $EXECSCRIPT
```

Strangely, foo.sh is always executed on two CPUs of the same node :(

So: Why does pbs(dsh) schedule my task onto one node, even though I have specified nodes=2:ppn=1? (And do I have to give these parameters in both of my scripts?)

---

Update: if foo.sh consists of

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "foostart" >> /home/farago/output.txt
cat $PBS_NODEFILE >> /home/farago/output.txt
echo "fooend" >> /home/farago/output.txt
```

then I get output.txt:

```
foostart
cn11
cn11
fooend
foostart
cn11
cn11
fooend
```

So it seems that giving the parameter -l nodes=2:ppn=1  twices results in both qsub and pbsdsh distributing the job twice. But I still do not understand why the jobs are not scheduled on different machines.

Comment: Can you add the line cat $PBS_NODEFILE to your job and post the output produced?

Comment: dbeer: I've updated my original post.

Comment: What scheduler do you use?

Comment: how do I find out which scheduler I use?

Comment: If you're running TORQUE then you are probably using Moab, Maui, or PBSPro to schedule. Who is your sysadmin? They should be able to tell you which scheduler you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only being launched on one node because your job is only running on one node. I'm not sure why your scheduler is launching you on only cn11, but the $PBS_NODEFILE tells you what hosts your job is using.

Some schedulers combine your request onto 1 node if possible, even the value for nodes is > 1. This part isn't strange.

Comment: Oh, some schedulers do that, very helpful to know (+1). Do you know how I change the scheduler or forbid him to combine?

Comment: I've updated my original post, which shows that somehow cn11 is output twice in one run. Also strange, but not a scheduler problem. Right?

Comment: I updated my answer now that I see that its just being executed twice.